# Windows Powershell for automating click on input tag (image type) with onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, powershell

I am trying to automate clicking an input tag with image type using this Powershell script. The script only opens the web page but does not click an invoke the javascript function. Am I missing something?

code in the page:

```
<input name="cv300$ctl42$g_11d90fd5_84d4_40f9_b5cc_e8ca081abd9b$btnExportCsv" title="Export to CSV file format" id="cv300_ctl42_g_11d90fd5_84d4_40f9_b5cc_e8ca081abd9b_btnExportCsv" style="border-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" onkeypress="" onclick='javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("cv300$ctl42$g_11d90fd5_84d4_40f9_b5cc_e8ca081abd9b$btnExportCsv", "", true, "", "", false, false))' type="image" alt="" src="/_layouts/15/images/ICXLS.GIF">
```

My Powershell script:

```
$url = "https://sharepoint/site/page.aspx"
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application

$ie.Navigate2($url)
$ie.Visible = $false

while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100}
$img = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq "image" -and $_.id -eq "cv300_ctl42_g_11d90fd5_84d4_40f9_b5cc_e8ca081abd9b_btnExportCsv"}
$img.click()
```

Comment: Have you verified that `$img` isn't null by outputting something like the title?

Comment: Are the random looking strings in the ID dynamically generated and different on every page load? Can you use a GetElementById function to go directly to it?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler no it's the same ID for each page load. Tried this but same result: `$img = $ie.Document.getElementById("cv300_ctl42_g_11d90fd5_84d4_40f‌​9_b5cc_e8ca081abd9b_‌​btnExportCsv") | Where-Object {$_.TagName -eq "input" -and $_.type -eq "image"} $img.click()`